# Google maps reverse geocoder returning gibberish instead of city name?

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask, reverse-geocoding

I am making an app for android. I am reverse geocoding a set of coordinates using Google maps reverse geocoder, and parsing the JSON that is returned to extract the city name. But instead of a city name like "New York", it is returning `com.example.geocoding_example.ParsingAsyncClass@418efd90(4025)`

What am I doing wrong to get this instead of a real answer? Thanks.

Here is the ParsingAsyncClass:

```
package com.example.gecoding_example;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ParsingAsyncClass extends AsyncTask {
    String cityName = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
        {double latitude=40.7130;
        double longitude=74.0135;
        final AndroidHttpClient ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(GecodingActivity.class.getName());

            String googleMapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +latitude + ","
                    +longitude + "&sensor=false&language=fr";

            try
            {
                JSONObject googleMapResponse = new JSONObject(ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT.execute(new HttpGet(googleMapUrl),
                        new BasicResponseHandler()));

                // many nested loops.. not great -> use expression instead
                // loop among all results
                JSONArray results = (JSONArray) googleMapResponse.get("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
                {
                    // loop among all addresses within this result
                    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (result.has("address_components"))
                    {
                        JSONArray addressComponents = result.getJSONArray("address_components");
                        // loop among all address component to find a 'locality' or 'sublocality'
                        for (int j = 0; j < addressComponents.length(); j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject addressComponent = addressComponents.getJSONObject(j);
                            if (result.has("types"))
                            {
                                JSONArray types = addressComponent.getJSONArray("types");

                                // search for locality and sublocality


                                for (int k = 0; k < types.length(); k++)
                                {
                                    if ("locality".equals(types.getString(k)) && cityName == null)
                                    {
                                        if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                        }
                                        else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if ("sublocality".equals(types.getString(k)))
                                    {
                                        if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                        }
                                        else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (cityName != null)
                                {
                                    Log.d("Geoco== "+cityName, "tag");
                                    return cityName;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(e.toString(),"tag");
            }
            return null;
        }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object cityaName){
        super.onPostExecute(cityaName);
        String a;
        a=cityaName.toString();
        if (cityaName != null)
        {
            // Do something with cityName
            Log.d("GeocoderHelpe123" +
                    "r"+cityaName, "tag");
        }else{Log.d("GeocoderHelper232"+cityaName, "tag");}
    }

}
```

Comment: `Log.d("Geoco== "+cityName, "tag");`. What does this line print to you?

Comment: @iturki It prints `Geoco== com.example.geocoding_example.ParsingAsyncClass@418efd90(4025)` inside the LogCat.

Comment: Could you post the lat & lng you used?

Comment: @iturki latitude=40.7130,
        longitude=74.0135

Comment: Whic one of the last `log`s is printing? is `cityName` returned null?

Comment: @iturki Only the `Log.d("Geoco== "+cityName, "tag");` log is printing, the logs in `onPostExecute()` are not printing. No, cityName is not returned null, it is returning the jibberish value I wrote in the question.

Comment: `onPostExecute(Object cityaName)` Change the parameter type to `String`. I'm not sure if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to get (lots of Googleing and trial-and-error), but it works.

```
protected class RetrieveGoogleMapsCityName extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
    protected AppCompatActivity a;
    protected AlertDialog dialog;

    private RetrieveGoogleMapsCityName(AppCompatActivity a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.a).create();
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.setMessage("*****");
        this.dialog.setTitle("*****");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            final HttpURLConnection conn;
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),
                    "UTF-8"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONArray results = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONArray address_components = results.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                    //Log.v("JSONArray", address_components.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name"));
                    //Log.v("JSONArrayTypes", address_components.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types").getString(0));

                    if (address_components.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types").getString(0).contentEquals("locality")) {
                        Log.v("JSONArray:i", i + " " + address_components.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name"));
                        cityName = address_components.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name");
                    }
                    if (address_components.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types").getString(0).contentEquals("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                        stateLetters = address_components.getJSONObject(i).getString("short_name");
                    }
                }
                /*cityName =
                        obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONArray("address_components").getJSONObject(1).getString("long_name");
                stateLetters = obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONArray("address_components").getJSONObject(4).getString("short_name");*/
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
        hasLocation = true;
        Log.v("onPostExecute", "You are located in " + cityName + ", " + stateLetters);
    }
}
```

**Result: You are located in Charlotte, NC**
**Result 2: You are located in London, England**

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `toString()` on the class, but have not implemented a `toString()` method that returns the properties you are interested in. What you are seeing is the hexadecimal representation of the hash code of your object.

```
a=cityaName.toString();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, on how to get the right text output? I have a Log.d inside the doInBackground method, and that returns the gibberish value. I haven't used toString() in there yet.

Comment: You only posted part of your code... whatever is passing the `Object` to `onPostExecute()` needs to pass a string for the city name or an object with the city name as a property, for example `String city = myObj.cityName;`